# Need to a vertical alignment of a p tag within different divs

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

Hey I'm working on a site and it happens that I'm trying to do a vertical alignment of a p tag within different divs (with different heights) but I'm not able to. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to share some code with us, maybe a fiddle or something. It's impossible to help you right now.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on jsfiddle, works. Width, height and border were used to demonstrate the alignment. Requires CSS3 browser support.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #000000;">
    <p style="display:block; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); margin: auto; border: 1px dashed red; width: 100px; text-align: center;">Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesnt work - look at this slightly edited version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/wL9mq8k3/

Comment: Updated with CSS3, much simpler to use. BTW the previous one worked if you adjusted the height with javascript, I mentioned that. Now this is pure CSS3.